# Struts2 Value Stack

Tags: struts2

I want to understand Struts 2 value stack vs request scope.
I want the struts2 value stack to work same as request scope.

for e.g.
i have invoked action1 in struts 2, the action performs some db task and gets back. it performs some operation on a object called cases (type Cases, where Cases is bean class with getters and setters). cases object is declared at class level.

action1 led a view to be rendered say jsp1.

jsp1 again has some action called as action2. action2 leads to the same java file as of action1 but has different method.

Now, i want to access the object which was used in action1. during action1 cases was pushed to Value Stack and was accessed on jsp1.

I simply tried accessing its getter methods, but it returns a null value....!!

any solution on how to do ??? or is it possible ?? i know if its possible then what is the difference between vs and request scope...

Comment: The value stack is *in* the request scope. Your question is confusing.

Comment: The value stack, like request scope, doesn't remember anything from one request to another.

Answer (score 1):

What Dave says about the ValueStack being in the request scope is correct.

But to achieve what you desire as far as acquiring some data from a database once and then using this data over multiple actions/requests, a few possible approaches can be used:

1)  Have your action implement the [SessionAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html) interface, and write some code to "manually" get and put the data from/into the session map.  This approach requires zero additional configuration and is very straight-forwared and "magicless".  On the other hand, it adds boiler-plate code to your action class and requires you to "manually" remove the data from the session when you are done with it (or, you could just leave it there if saving memory is not important).

2)  Have your action implement the [ModelDriven](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/model-driven.html) interface and configure the [ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/scoped-model-driven-interceptor.html) to manage the session scope of your "cases" model.  This is less-simple than the SessionAware approach as it requires referring to the documentation to add some very specific configuration details to your struts.xml.  It still requires the addition of boiler-plate code and it does not offer a simple way to remove the data from the session.

3)  Use the [Struts2 Conversation Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/), and put the @ConversationField annotation on your cases object and put the @ConversationAction annotation on the action1 and action2 methods.  Then in your struts.xml have your package extend the "struts2-conversation-default" package and include the "conversation" interceptor-ref in your interceptor stack.  Then in your jsp, use the [conversation tags](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/#tag_lib).  This approach requires little boiler-plate and configuration, but it does add meta-data via annotations to your actions (some people will frown at that) and it does require learning a little more.  The plugin has extra functionality such as allowing multiple, concurrent instances of the same conversation, automatic removal of the data to conserve memory, etc., but, depending on your needs, this could be overkill.

The best approach for your app will depend on your requirements and preferences.  Accessing the session object using `ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` should be avoided in action classes in favor of the SessionAware interface.

Answer (score 0):

The object that you create in first request cannot be referenced in the second request because [HTTP protocol is stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

It is same for all web programming (PHP,servlet jsp,asp etc), because web use HTTP protocol to communicate.

The viable solutions for you problem:

1 .Create hidden input tag that contain the object id, so that when you request for the second time, the struts 2 method can get the id (as parameter) and do the "action performs some db task" again to recreate the same object (it is expensive to create it again but it depends on your needs)

or

2 .Before you render the jsp in the first request, you can put the object in session scope (better to do this step in action, not in jsp scriplet).

> ```
> Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
> session.put("myCases","cases);
> ```

in the second request you can access the object

> ```
> Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
> Cases cases=(Cases)session.get("myCases");
> ```

the session can be accessed in any actions/jsp until it removed.

> ```
> Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
> session.remove("myCases");
> ```

you will get null if you try to accessed "myCases" after it removed from session.